# Can we make something like comodo firewall in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

AFAIK, one might need to work on the low level linux to do this job or use theorem provers to anlayze programs without having to understanding the underlying programs. In addition, AFAIK each program is controlled in its own sandbox so that it does not affect other programs.

However, during the past year, researchers have demonstrated that they could "borrow" permission from other programs even if their programs did not initially ask for them. This unfortunately makes Android much less trustworthy as its security model is essentially permission-based at install time ONLY. I guess one way to ensure that this kind of attacks (I mean malicously acquiring permissions a program should not have had) would be to monitor inter-programs communications and in real time.

Since dalvik is not open source, and neither is Android itself (apart from open API's), can anyone think of a way, using Java only, to implement a dynamic and realtime firewall in Android that would at least ensure no program can start another without our explicit permission each time (more like how comodo firewall works)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not possible at the "Java" level. There is no way to deal with IP at that level, never-mind no way to intercept it or universally act as a proxy.

Comment: uh, both Android and the dalvik vm and spec are open source

Comment: Wesley, many thanks for your answer, Would you mind referring me to the documentations that support your statement?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Before making any software you might have complete understanding about the functionality of that software. You are trying to make software like comodo firewall then you must know that how comodo firewall works, how it block any software activity, how it monitor network activity and many other activity that comodo firewall can do. if you don't have basic understanding about that then first understand it then think next..
Download it from here and understand it..

http://www.filekb.com/windows/download-comodo-firewall/